# Is there way to have existing bcp calls still work if column is added to table in sybase?

Tags: sybase, bcp

I have a bunch of client programs that call bcp to put data into to a sybase table.

I need to add a column to the sybase table.  If I default the column to a value, and/or allow nulls, will the existing clients still work with no changes to them?

The existing clients will still call bcp with the Old number of fields, and will not include the extra column in the bcp input data file.

Comment: Do your clients currently use a format file as part of the BCP?

Answer (score 0):

default works in BCP, but you have to add column seperator at the end of each row of input file  to make bcp work.